# How to get list of identity users emails using Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-identity

I'm trying to write a custom validation that only allows you to enter an e-mail of a person who has sign up for my application I have the validation working for hard coded emails but I can't get a list from my identity users. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my validation class

```
namespace IncidentReportForm.CustomValidation
{
    public class EmailVAlidation : ValidationAttribute
    {
        public override bool IsValid(object value)
        {
            String email = Convert.ToString(value);

            if (email == "sample@gmail.com")
            {
                UserManager userManager = UserManager
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

I know that the `UserManager` class has queryable users that can be used to get list of emails but I don't know how to call the `UserManager` object that they are stored in. As I can't just initialize a new `UserManager` object.

Comment: Usually you would DI the usermanager

Comment: Thank You. I fixed it by making a static UserManager object in the class and set it using the DI in controller constructor.